# Create label Click in InputBox

Tags: c#, click, label, inputbox

I have a function, `private void sentEmail()` in `Form1`. And I want to use that function to a label in a InputBox.

The InputBox that I use is this: http://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox/

I creat a new class and add the code of InputBox.

In InputBox I creat the label:

```
Label label2 = new Label();
label2.Text = mesaj;
label2.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
```

Now I need to make this: when the InputBox will appears, when I will click on `label2`, to use the function from `Form1`. The `label2` is a text for recive the password, function work, but I need to use the function in InputBox but I don't know how to do this.
I think that I need to creat a new **Handler**, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `InputBox` method to

```
public static DialogResult InputBox(string title, string promptText, ref string value, Action labelClickCallback)
```

and add that callback to the Click event.

```
Label label2 = new Label();
label2.Text = mesaj;
label2.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
label2.Click += (s, e) => labelClickCallback(); // Create a new event handler
```

When calling the `InputBox` method, you can now pass a method to the method which will be called when the user clicks on the label. Call `InputBox` like this:

```
InputBox("Title", "Text", ref result, sentEmail);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Label` has a [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=vs.80%29) event.

```
label2.Click += delegate {
    form1.sendEmail();
}
```

Comment: The function sentMail is not in Inputbox, is in Form1. And don't work in your way. label2.Click += delegate { sentEmail(); } - error: ; Expected

Comment: @AnDr3yy you didn't say whether the label is created within `Form1` or not which I just assumed. See update.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have the `SendMail()` method in an other class, not in `Form1`, you may want to use it somewhere else.

```
public class MailController
{
    public void SendEmail()
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

And in your form, you just call it after instantiate the class containing it

```
//Your form containing the InputBox
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label2 = new Label();
    label2.Text = mesaj;
    label2.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

    label2.Click += OnLabelClick;
}

private void OnLabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailController controller = new MailController();
    controller.SendMail();
}
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer. I don't try your method becouse the BigYellowCactus's methos work perfectly. But tnx !!

Comment: Glade you sloved the problem ;)